# Memory limit wamp x64 bigger than 4GB

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have install WAMP server X64 on my  localhost and was expecting to make it work over 4GB (I have installed 8 GB), so I edited the php.ini the variable to `memory_limit = 6000 M` so it uses 6 GB but doesn't work, I get

`[05-Nov-2016 14:26:29 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 989 bytes) in F:\SERVER\www\index.php on line 141`

If I add 4095 M it works. And it is indeed the x64 version for apache and for WAMP

WAMP X64 Proof

[image]

APACHE 64 bit proof

[image]

PHP VERSION - Says archtecture 64.

[image]

What should I do in order to get more than 4095 M?

Comment: PHP might still be only x86. Check phpinfo.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Says archtecture x64. Attached screenshoot.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39132&edit=1 But the question should anyway be "What am I doing that needs >4G memory inside an apache process with PHP and is this tool set best suited for the job?"

Comment: ___Just a note___ Windows PHP versions before PHP7.0.0 were not fully 64bit. Only after PHP7 is Windows PHP fully 64bit

Comment: The same issue is with apache 2.4 and php 5.6.29 (all x64 compiled with VC11). Can't set memory limit more than 4gb. Both in web and CLI runtime.